# "blur shadow" messes up other nodes!

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-blur

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{MyNode}=[%
  minimum height=8mm, minimum width=10mm,
  blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},
  fill=gray]

\begin{scope}
\node[MyNode]{A};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \node at (1,0){A-bg};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=55mm]
\node[MyNode]{A};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \node at (1,0){A-bg};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When the line `blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}` exists, content of `\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}` won't be in the PDF (or at least I cannot see it). When I comment that line, I can see it. What is it that I am missing? (I tried this code on overleaf and on my computer with `pdflatex`. The behavior is the same.) Below pictures are screenshots when the line is commented or not commented.

EDIT: I updated the code to show why switching the order of scopes does not help (no matter what order you put them, the one that comes first is missing the content of its `\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}`).

[image: no-blur]

[image: blur]

Comment: `pdflatex --version` gives me `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)`. I tried Adobe Acrobat, the Preview that is the default app for this on macOS, and whatever is used internally by VS Code and Overleaf.

Comment: My bad. I didn't read the question carefully enough. +1. If you change the order, it seems to work.

Comment: Changing the order does not help me, since in my complete example, both nodes on the right sides should have the blur and both nodes in the left sides should have the `\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}`.

Comment: I meant put `\begin{scope}[xshift=55mm]
\node[MyNode]{A};
\end{scope}` before the other stuff.

Comment: I understand. That does not help. Suppose the content of both scopes is `\node[MyNode]{A};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \node at (1,0){A-bg};
\end{pgfonlayer}` (the only difference is one of them is shifted). Then it does not matter which one comes first.

Comment: I do not understand the last comment but reordering is at best a workaround.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat sugestion: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shadows.blur}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
MyNode/.style = {minimum height=8mm, minimum width=15mm,
                 fill=gray,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}}
                        ]
\begin{scope}[xshift=55mm]
\node[MyNode]{A};
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \node{A-bg};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\node{A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`   
 works fine!

Answer (score 2):

This is only (and at best) a workaround. You can place the background node *after* the node with the shadow. (Placing it before sort of defeats the purpose of putting it on a lower layer, but I understand that this is just a minimal working example and that there can be situations where this really makes sense.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[MyNode/.style={minimum height=8mm, minimum width=15mm,
  blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},
  fill=gray
  }]
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

\begin{scope}
\node{A};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=55mm]
\node[MyNode]{A};
\end{scope}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
 \node{A-bg};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the question why this happens I am not entirely sure. Both the layers and `shadows.blur` create some boxes that they shift around. For some reason the creation of the boxes by `shadows.blur` seems to destroy the boxes on the background layer. (However, putting `\node[MyNode]{A};` on the `bg` layer also solves the problem.

If there is a real answer, I will be happy to remove this workaround.